# Javascript sort object by values and keys when values are same

Tags: javascript, loops, sorting, object

I have an Javascript object for example

`{ "g":-3, "e":2, "n":-3, "b": -3, "f": -5}`

I need to sort it by values but if the values are the same, then I need to sort it by key.

goal => `{"e":2, "b":-3, "g":-3, "n": -3, "f": -5}`

thank you

Comment: In general you shouldn't depend on the order of entries in objects. Use an array if order is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *convert* your object into an array of arrays first using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and the simply [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) according to your criterion. Finally *convert* the sorted 2d array back to an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
const data = { g: -3, e: 2, n: -3, b: -3, f: -5 };

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(data).sort((a, b) =>
    b[1] - a[1] !== 0 ? b[1] - a[1] : a[0].localeCompare(b[0])
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

I'm positive there is a more efficient way of solving this, yet I personally think it's quite traceable that way.

Comment: Thank you I tried localCompare but I didn't use the correct logic.